# Cannot connect to external PostgreSQL database from dockerized Django

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running Django application dockerized and trying to connect to PostgreSQL database that is located at external host with a public IP.

When running a container, `makemigrations` command falls with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "myhost" (89.xx.xx.102) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

However, it successfully connects when not dockerized.

Here the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 65534:65534
```

and corresponding `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10 AS builder
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn


FROM builder
COPY ./ /app/
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

and `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

python /app/manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
python /app/manage.py makemigrations
python /app/manage.py migrate --no-input
gunicorn --pythonpath /app/ -b 0.0.0.0:65534 app.wsgi:application
```

How to make it possible for the Django application to connect to externally hosted PostgresSQL database?

Comment: When it is dockerized, is django still running on your development machine, or deployed to another machine?  If different host, maybe postgres isn't accepting from the docker one.  Can you establish that the host the dockerized django is on has an outbound path to the postgres server?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to deploy both database and dockerized application at one host machine, but make Django app connect to database via public hostname, not the localhost and etc. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know what the docker will think its own hostname is and if it will be able to resolve the name, but likely that's related to the symptom. Can you install ping/traceroute stuff in the container and see if it is finding the host machine by name?  And search for "docker use server on same host by hostname"

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run below command:

```
vim /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf #14 is the version of postgres.
```

Uncomment and edit the listen_addresses attribute to start listening to start listening to all available IP addresses.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Append a new connection policy (a pattern stands for [CONNECTION_TYPE][DATABASE][USER] [ADDRESS][METHOD]) in the bottom of the file.

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

We are allowing TCP/IP connections (host) to all databases (all) for all users (all) with any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0/0) using an MD5 encrypted password for authentication (md5).

It is now time to restart your PostgreSQL service to load your configuration changes.

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```

And make sure your system is listening to the 5432 port that is reserved for PostgreSQL.

```
ss -nlt | grep 5432
```

**Connect to PostgreSQL database through a remote host:**

Your PostgreSQL server is now running and listening for external requests. It is now time to connect to your database through a remote host.

**Connect via Command Line Tool:**

You may now connect to a remote database by using the following command pattern:

```
psql -h [ip address] -p [port] -d [database] -U [username]
```

Let’s now connect to a remote PostgreSQL database that we have hosted.

```
psql -h 5.199.162.56 -p 5432 -d test_erp -U postgres
```

To double check your connection details use the **\conninfo** command.

Comment: The problem is that PostgreSQL is deployed on external machine, not the one where dockerized Django application resides. 65534 is the port for Django server

Comment: are you working on ubuntu machine

Comment: Yes, both apps deployed on Ubuntu

Comment: PostgreSQL is working just fine when trying to connect from host. But the Django application that is run via Docker cannot resolve it

Comment: The PostgreSQL is configured on that port. The Django server configured at port 65534.

Comment: try to use both ports in docker-compose file